# Looking for an electronic copy of Lebeau's paper

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, oc.optimization-and-control, schrodinger-operators

I would like to know if anyone has an electronic copy of the paper "Gilles Lebeau - Contrôle De L'Équation De Schrödinger"? This article appeared in Journal de Mathématiques Pures et Appliquées, Vol. 71, (1992), no. 3, 267–291.

The website of the [Bibliothèque nationale de France  - Gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb343487840/date.r=.langEN) has all volumes all volumes published by this journal from 1836 to 1945 and the website of the [journal](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/journal-de-mathematiques-pures-et-appliquees/issues?page=2), the volumes published from 1997 to the present.

So I couldn’t find that article on the internet.

Comment: I've checked in my institutional library. Most likely, it seems those volumes of the journal were not digitized. Plus the physical library is off-limits due to COVID-19, but they didn't have paper copies in any case. I think this will be difficult unless someone who has physical copies of the journal sees this and contacts you.

Comment: The years from 1946 to 1996 have not been digitized yet (or they have been, but are not yet available on the web): however, I think that you could find a library that have not been blocked by the COVID-19, and ask them for a digitized scam of the paper. Otherwise you could ask [him](https://math.unice.fr/laboratoire/fiche&id=224) directly a paper copy.

Comment: This is an old post, so you may no longer be interested in the paper. However, if you are, I have a copy. I don't have a link or anything, but I'd be happy to email it to you.